# Java regex for hasNext() that matches end of next

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

Suppose I construct a new Scanner from an input file

```
Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("file.txt"));
```

and the file.txt has multiple lines like this

```
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah
```

I want check whether the Scanner has a next value matching my pattern:

```
 aScanner.hasNext("blah");
```

That works fine. However, when I try using the end of line character $:

```
 aScanner.hasNext("blah$");
```

It fails. It even fails when I flag for multiple lines (?m). Then I realized that $ matches the end of the string, or the end of the input, which is neither of the cases presented (except at the very end). Given this, how would I match the end of next input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter passed to `hasNext()` is the pattern for the **delimiter**, which is then **consumed** upon calling `next()`.

Try using a look-behind instead:

```
aScanner.hasNext("(?<=blah)\\s+");
```

This says use whitespace as a delimiter, but only if preceded by "blah", although this would consume everything up to a "blah", skipping over other chars as required.

Answer (score 1):

`hasNext("blah$")` can only match when the next token is the string "blah" followed by the end of the file (or end of a line with `(?m)`.

This may be instructive:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new StringReader("blah blah\nblah blah"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(s.hasNext("blah"));
        System.out.println(s.hasNext("blah$"));
        System.out.println(s.hasNext("(?m)blah$"));
        s.next();
    }
}
```

There are four blah's there. The first is only matched by `hasNext("blah")`. The second is matched by that as well as by `hasNext("(?m)blah$")` because it's at the end of a line. The third is again matched only by `hasNext("blah")`. The fourth matches all of the conditions because it's both at the end of a line and the end of the file.

Comment: So there's no character that denotes the end of a hasNext() value that is neither the end of the line or the end of the file?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Perhaps you could clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve instead of saying what *doesn't* work.